# What is burstable RAM given in VPS specification

Tags: centos, memory

MY hosting provider has given me the 768MB RAM but it was written that burstable RAM is 1504+.
I want to know what does that mean

Answer (score 1):

It means that you've paid for 768, but, if you briefly need more, it will let you take to 1504, however, they will come down on you if it does it often, such as if you run something overnight every night that bursts over 768, even to 834, they will start telling you you need to upgrade.